# "We met" vs We've met"

Tags: grammar, usage

Can somebody please explain the different between the following sentences?

"Thank you to all of the people we've met and worked with in 2018."

&

"Thank you to all of the people we met and worked with in 2018."

When I try to look up the grammar rules for the usage of adding "have" in this particular case or not, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence only the second action (THEY WORKED WITH IN 2018) refers to the definite completed past period (THEY HAVE MET AND ARE STILL IN TOUCH NOW). 
In the second sentence both actions refer to the definite completed  past period (THEY MET AND WORKED WITH ONLY IN 2018, BUT NOW THEY'RE NOT IN TOUCH).